# How to use a ValidationMonitor for an Estimator in TensorFlow 1.0?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

TensorFlow provides the possibility for combining ValidationMonitors with several predefined estimators like *tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier*.
But I want to use a ValidationMonitor for my own estimator which I have created based on [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started#a_custom_model).

For my own estimator I initialize first a ValidationMonitor:

```
validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(testX,testY,every_n_steps=50)

estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=model,model_dir=direc,config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=1))

input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x": x}, y, 4, num_epochs=1000)
```

**Here I pass the monitor as shown in [2](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/monitors) for tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier:**

```
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000,monitors=[validation_monitor])
```

This fails and following error was printed:

> ValueError: Features are incompatible with given information. Given features: Tensor("input:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float64), required signatures: {'x': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.float64, shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None)]), is_sparse=False)}.

How can I use monitors for my own estimators?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved when passing *input_fn* containing *testX* and *testY* to  *ValidationMonitor* instead of passing the tensors *testX* and *testY* directly.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, your error was caused by the fact that ValidationMonitor expects x to be a dictionary like `{ 'feature_name_as_a_string' : feature_tensor }`, which in your `input_fn` is done internally by the call to `tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn(...)`.

More information about how to build features dictionaries can be found in the [Building Input Functions with tf.contrib.learn article of the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn).